# Upload file feature for spring-graphql

Tags: graphql-java, spring-graphql

Is there a roadmap to make uploading files available in the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [dedicated issue for multipart file upload](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/issues/69), but this is not yet scheduled in our roadmap.